# Wicket datatable change font or css of cell after onchange

Tags: java, javascript, css, datatable, wicket

In my application I have a defaultDataTable, with a clickable column and a search field to filter the table. The filter filters the content of the datatable after a character is inserted into the input field. My goal is to underline (or other css) the parts of the text in the fields that apply to the input of the user.

Example: The characters 'a' and 'b' of the string 'abc' should be underlined if the user enters 'ab'. With Javascript I can add some styling, but my function does some strange things with the datatable. It deletes everything inside the table tags en puts the new html there. All the other information is gone. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    $('.searchField').keyup(function(){
        var page = $('.datatable');
        alert(page.text());
        var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
        alert(pageText);
        var searchedText = $('#searchField').val();
        var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    

        var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<b>$1</b>");
        alert(newHtml);
        page.html(newHtml);
   });
</script>
```

New table:

```
<table id="ID" class="datatable" wicket:id="ID">
Col1 Col2 123
<b>MATCHEDCHAR</b>
TEXT
<b>MATCHEDCHAR</b>
TEXT
</table>
```

Old table (collapsed body en head):

```
<table id="ID" class="datatable" wicketsource="URL.java" wicket:id="ID">
<thead wicketsource="org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table:DataTable.java:181" wicket:id="topToolbars">
<tbody wicketsource="org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table:DataTable.java:207" wicket:id="body">
<tr class="even" wicketsource="org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table:DefaultDataTable.java:71" wicket:id="rows">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a handler on `searchField` which perform table refresh.
So all you need is just to subcribe on `complete ajax event`.

```
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/complete', function(jqEvent, attributes, jqXHR, errorThrown, textStatus) {
  // call code that highlight the text
});
```

You can put this subscription method in the page(in a `script` tag).
If you want to link js call to a specific behavior say `OnChangeAjaxBehavior`, then you need to call `target.appendJavaScript`:

```
    new OnChangeAjaxBehavior(){
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.appendJavaScript("<call highlight function here>");
        }
    };
```

Try [this](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) jquery highlight plugin.
More about ajax global call listeners [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-ajax.html).

I've made a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S8ydD/) so you can check it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand how to subscribe to the ajax event. My searchfield has an onChangeAjaxBehavior & onUpdate attached to it, but the wicket.event.subscribe is never called. How do you connect them?

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it. Accept the answer if it solves your problem please.

Comment: Code I put inside the wicket.event.subscribe never gets called and if I call a function outside the wicket.event.subscribe I cannot access the values of the datatable. #wicketiddatatable or something like that does not work. Sorry I am still nog getting it, hopefully you are prepared to help me a bit more.

Comment: Check this out https://mega.co.nz/#!XZoG3LzI!WFNwvG_NWIEMOCtNDjZUN3_ZCUAVlQmAOBoTJmmH4q4

Comment: Most "wicketish way" seems to prepare two css descriptors in constant css sheet, and change only component attribute in kind `arg0.getAttributes().put("class", "alternative_css_class");`